# getXYZ() returning incorrect values?

Tags: python, game-engine, vertices

Given a plane like this:

[image]

I want to sort the vertices from left to right, top to bottom (for use in the BGE).

However, `vertex.getXYZ()` and `vertex.XYZ` give incorrect values for several vertices. I've checked the plane for doubles, yet a number of verts return the same locations.

```
from bge import logic

own = logic.getCurrentController().owner
vertlist = []

def sort_verts(k):

    if k['XYZ'][0] < 0:
        return k['XYZ'][1]+.0001
    else:
       return k['XYZ'][1]


for mesh in own.meshes:
    for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
        for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):
            vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)

            print(v_index, mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index).getXYZ())


            vertlist.append({"XYZ": vertex.XYZ.copy(), "index": v_index})

vertlist.sort(key=sort_verts)     

#for v in vertlist:
#    print(v['index'], v['XYZ'])
```

<sup>I've commented out the sorting part, as it doesn't seem to be causing the problem.</sup>

Running the above in the BGE outputs the following:
I've commented a few of the duplicates, there might be more.

```
Blender Game Engine Started
0 <Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)>
1 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.9310, 0.0000)>
2 <Vector (1.0000, 0.9310, 0.0000)>
3 <Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)>
4 <Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)>
5 <Vector (1.0000, -0.9310, 0.0000)>
6 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.9310, 0.0000)>
7 <Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)>
8 <Vector (1.0000, -0.8621, 0.0000)>
9 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.8621, 0.0000)>
10 <Vector (1.0000, -0.5172, 0.0000)>
11 <Vector (1.0000, -0.4483, 0.0000)>
12 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.4483, 0.0000)>
13 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.5172, 0.0000)>
14 <Vector (1.0000, -0.3793, 0.0000)>
15 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.3793, 0.0000)>
16 <Vector (1.0000, -0.3103, 0.0000)>
17 <Vector (1.0000, -0.2414, 0.0000)>
18 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.2414, 0.0000)>
19 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.3103, 0.0000)>
20 <Vector (1.0000, -0.7241, 0.0000)>
21 <Vector (1.0000, -0.6552, 0.0000)>
22 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.6552, 0.0000)>
23 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.7241, 0.0000)>
24 <Vector (1.0000, -0.5862, 0.0000)>
25 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.5862, 0.0000)>
26 <Vector (1.0000, -0.7931, 0.0000)>
27 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.7931, 0.0000)>
28 <Vector (1.0000, -0.1724, 0.0000)>
29 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.1724, 0.0000)> # same as 35
30 <Vector (1.0000, -0.1034, 0.0000)>
31 <Vector (1.0000, -0.0345, 0.0000)>
32 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.0345, 0.0000)>
33 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.1034, 0.0000)> # same as 34
34 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.1034, 0.0000)> # same as 33
35 <Vector (-1.0000, -0.1724, 0.0000)> # same as 29
36 <Vector (1.0000, 0.0345, 0.0000)>
37 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.0345, 0.0000)>
38 <Vector (1.0000, 0.1035, 0.0000)>
39 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.1035, 0.0000)>
40 <Vector (1.0000, 0.1724, 0.0000)> # same as 42
41 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.1724, 0.0000)> # same as 45
42 <Vector (1.0000, 0.1724, 0.0000)> # same as 41
43 <Vector (1.0000, 0.2414, 0.0000)>
44 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.2414, 0.0000)>
45 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.1724, 0.0000)> # same as 41
46 <Vector (1.0000, 0.3103, 0.0000)>
47 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.3103, 0.0000)>
48 <Vector (1.0000, 0.3793, 0.0000)>
49 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.3793, 0.0000)>
50 <Vector (1.0000, 0.4483, 0.0000)>
51 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.4483, 0.0000)>
52 <Vector (1.0000, 0.5172, 0.0000)>
53 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.5172, 0.0000)>
54 <Vector (1.0000, 0.5862, 0.0000)>
55 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.5862, 0.0000)>
56 <Vector (1.0000, 0.6552, 0.0000)>
57 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.6552, 0.0000)>
58 <Vector (1.0000, 0.7241, 0.0000)>
59 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.7241, 0.0000)>
60 <Vector (1.0000, 0.7931, 0.0000)>
61 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.7931, 0.0000)>
62 <Vector (1.0000, 0.8621, 0.0000)>
63 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.8621, 0.0000)>
Blender Game Engine Finished
```

[image]

What gives?

---

I just noticed that the BGE seems to think there are 64 vertices, but my plane only has 60 according to the count in the header.
What could cause this?

Comment: How many materials do you expect? 1,2 or more?  This relates to the unexpected count of 64.  How many faces of each material?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger 1. There *should* always be only one in my particular case (and there is only one in the example, I checked that). Even stranger, it correctly gives 4 verts if I delete the extra edges in the plane.

Comment: Take this with a cellar of salt.  2013.  https://developer.blender.org/T34550

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Hm.. That may relevant still. The result seems vary based on how I construct the plane. If I do more than 15 loopcuts at once, it returns extra verts. If I loopcut + subdivide (for e.g.) it works fine. Very strange indeed.

Comment: `getXYZ()` returns the position relative to the origin of the mesh. The vertex count and the duplicates are related. Basically it's nesscesary for the GPU in some cases (related to face normals) to duplicate some verticies. BGE does that for you without you noticing, until you count the vertices that's it. Don't worry about it and handle the duplicates as if they where the same vertex.

If at some point you want to modify the normals then you'll have a problem.

Comment: @elmeunick I see, so this is expected behavior. If you care to write that up in an answer I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [elmeunick's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43816/getxyz-returning-incorrect-values#comment74553_43816):

> `getXYZ()` returns the position relative to the origin of the mesh. The vertex count and the duplicates are related. Basically it's necessary for the GPU in some cases (related to face normals) to duplicate some vertices. BGE does that for you without you noticing, until you count the vertices that's it.
>
> Don't worry about it and handle the duplicates as if they where the same vertex. If at some point you want to modify the normals then you'll have a problem.